# What are John and Marsha's REAL names?

Tags: riddle

> Dear John,
>
> My actions fail me through the years
>   So now I'll speak through windswept tears.
>   I'll never get your wandering ways;
>   Remote attention fickly sways.
>   You leave me swirling, dazed, and lost in gloom.
>
> To stalk is hardly my intent, no.
>   I follow you, so that you'll know
>   There's life inside me and I feel
>   The bond between you two is real.
>   Remember how we danced that night in June?
>
> You're cold, you're distant, tantalizing.
>   I don't think that you'd despise me.
>   I can see it, no use lying:
>   Your face would never truly rise
>   Against my salty eyes—you know it's true.
>
> I'll not give up;   yes, I have found
>   That men like you    will come around.
>   I'll channel deep,   I'll find the grace
>   I'll give you what you   need—your space—
>   And love you from my depths when you are blue.
>
> I love you.
>
> -Marsha

*What are John and Marsha's REAL names?*

Here's a subtle hint:

> [...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61764/what-are-john-and-marshas-real-names?noredirect=1#comment188399_61764)

Comment: Dangit I was trying to exploit that to solve the puzzle. I thought it was a clue :P

Comment: first thought would be the ocean and the moon? 
It fits nicely with mot of it, but there are some things that I can't get to fit with that answer.

Comment: @Stender which lines wouldn´t fit ?

Comment: @Doomenik `Remember how we danced that night in June?` makes no sense to me? I saw that there was a "Mini-moon" In june last year, But how is that dancing :)

Comment: @Stender Does this: (https://quizlet.com/119246740/romeo-juliet-figurative-language-in-act-2-scene-2-flash-cards/) help?

Comment: I hate that you can't google `Sun and moon` anymore :-D It basically just returns the pokemon game now!

Comment: @Stender you can omit items in searches: "sun and moon -pokemon," for instance, gives me many, *many* Chinese restaurants!  :)

Comment: @Stender, check out my new hint

Comment: @Stender Click on the new hint :D

Comment: Maybe John is the sun and Marsha is the moon. They dance in June because of an eclipse, “your face will never rise against my salty eyes” refers to how John rises as the sun and Marsha sets as the moon. Marsha is left in gloom, because the moon reflects the sun’s light. The sun and moon also need their own space in the sky and are quite distant. The moon also “follows” the sun via orbit. What do you think?

Comment: @user477343 Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @PL457 because it doesn’t answer everything, but if u say so... I will do it tomorrow then. I have to go to sleep now. G’night :)

Comment: Haha - Awesome hint!  - Well i am glad that I had the right idea :) I didn't want to answer before I had all of the referrals - otherwise this would just be a guessing game.

Comment: I still vouch for solrock and lunatone ;)

Comment: At least I made a helpfull comment :)

Comment: @Stender Maybe you're an altruistic saint and not in it for the [money](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/reputation) :)  ...but there's no shame in answering when you have a decent idea, yet you're not sure it's right.

Comment: @Chowzen I'm not here for reputation :) Just here to chill. 
But I must say, This community is much kinder than stackoverflow :-D I will keep in mind that "Partial answers is not a crime"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess, triggered by comments (EDIT: augh!  It's Stender's exactly!  Ah well -- here is some more explanation to support his guess -- he gets the credit):
John is

> the moon

and Marsha is

> the sea

Dear John,

My actions fail me through the years
So now I'll speak through windswept tears.

> "windswept tears" -- wind on sea waters creates spray

I'll never get your wandering ways;

> The moon constantly revolves around the earth, where the sea is bound. [OP:It [wobbles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC7odtQHoPc), too]

Remote attention fickly sways.
You leave me swirling, dazed, and lost in gloom.

> The moon creates tides from afar.

To stalk is hardly my intent, no.
I follow you, so that you'll know
There's life inside me and I feel

> The sea holds plentiful sea life. [OP:The ocean ["follows" the moon](http://www.gly.uga.edu/railsback/Tides/TideBulges.jpeg)]

The bond between you two is real.
Remember how we danced that night in June?

> https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/news/high-tide-bulletin/summer-2017/ noted higher-than-normal tides [OP:This was a nod to the theory that life arose from tidal pools... and "June" simply **≃** a rhyme with "Gloom"

You're cold, you're distant, tantalizing.

> Metaphorical aspects given to the moon.

I don't think that you'd despise me.
I can see it, no use lying:
Your face would never truly rise
Against my salty eyes—you know it's true.

> The sea is salt water. [OP: the moon has a face that rises]

I'll not give up; yes, I have found
That men like you will come around.
I'll channel deep, I'll find the grace

> "channel" is a cue to the sea -- channels being waterways, like the English Channel [OP: men, like the "man in the moon"]

I'll give you what you need—your space—

> The moon is in space.

And love you from my depths when you are blue.

> The sea has depths, and folks are familiar with "blue moons".

I love you.

-Marsha

Comment: Good on ya Mate - Take my upvote.